# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'map') in react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I don't understand why I am getting this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'map') in react.js

Could someone explain to me why?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


const UsersList = () => {
  const LIST_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users "
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(LIST_URL)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => setUsers(json.results))
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <header>      
        <h1>My contact list</h1>
      </header>
      <section> 
        <ul>
          {users.map(user => (
            <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>
          ))}         
        </ul>
      </section>
    </>
  )
}

export default UsersList
```

Comment: I don't see any `results` object in the json response at the url endpoint you provided. So try `.then(json => setUsers(json))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no property as `json.results`, you should assign the `json` to the state as

```
setUsers(json)
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(LIST_URL)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => setUsers(json));
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

you must check if users is not array empty you can write like this:

```
return (
    <>
      <header>      
        <h1>My contact list</h1>
      </header>
      <section> 
        <ul>
          {users.length > 0 && users.map(user => (
            <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>
          ))}         
        </ul>
      </section>
    </>
  )
```

Comment: This is not the right solution because OP setting the value of `users` as `setUsers(json.results)` . But there is no `results` property on the `json` so it will assign `undefined`. when you check `users.length > 0` then it will throw error because there is not property `length` on the `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that was the issue